# Use button foreground color for vector icons placed on WPF buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I'm using custom styles for buttons in my WPF app which changes foreground color on mouse over. This behaviour works fine on buttons containing only text, but I don't know how to achieve this behaviour on buttons containing vector icons.

I have all app vector icons defined in my app-wide resource dictionary (Glyphs.xaml), for example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas x:Key="IconResume" x:Shared="False" Width="28" Height="28">
        <Path Fill="#444" Data="M14.811 0.308l12.876 12.876q0.345 0.345 0.345 0.816t-0.345 0.816l-12.876 12.876q-0.345 0.345-0.58 0.236t-0.236-0.58v-26.694q0-0.471 0.236-0.58t0.58 0.236zM4.71 26.767v-25.534q0-0.471 0.345-0.816t0.816-0.345h4.643q0.471 0 0.816 0.345t0.345 0.816v25.534q0 0.471-0.345 0.816t-0.816 0.345h-4.643q-0.471 0-0.816-0.345t-0.345-0.816z" />
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And then button as:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ResumeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource BorderlessButton}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Viewbox Child="{StaticResource IconResume}" Height="10" Margn="0,0,8,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Resume" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

So, when mouse is positioned over the button, text changes color to the foreground color defined in my `IsMouseOver` trigger of `BorderlessButton` style. But vector icon is still of color #444 (as defined in `Path.Fill`). Is there an easy way to bind color of vector icon (all canvas pathes) to the foreground color of the button?

Comment: please, show XAML of `BorderlessButton`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly bind `Path.Fill` to parent Button `Foreground`

```
<Canvas x:Key="IconResume" x:Shared="False" Width="28" Height="28">
    <Path Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Data="M14.811 0.308l12.876 12.876q0.345 0.345 0.345 0.816t-0.345 0.816l-12.876 12.876q-0.345 0.345-0.58 0.236t-0.236-0.58v-26.694q0-0.471 0.236-0.58t0.58 0.236zM4.71 26.767v-25.534q0-0.471 0.345-0.816t0.816-0.345h4.643q0.471 0 0.816 0.345t0.345 0.816v25.534q0 0.471-0.345 0.816t-0.816 0.345h-4.643q-0.471 0-0.816-0.345t-0.345-0.816z" />
</Canvas>
```

OR you can put triggers too for Path to set Fill according to your requirement:

```
 <Canvas x:Key="IconResume" x:Shared="False" Width="28" Height="28">
        <Path x:Name="myPath" Data="M14.811 0.308l12.876 12.876q0.345 0.345 0.345 0.816t-0.345 0.816l-12.876 12.876q-0.345 0.345-0.58 0.236t-0.236-0.58v-26.694q0-0.471 0.236-0.58t0.58 0.236zM4.71 26.767v-25.534q0-0.471 0.345-0.816t0.816-0.345h4.643q0.471 0 0.816 0.345t0.345 0.816v25.534q0 0.471-0.345 0.816t-0.816 0.345h-4.643q-0.471 0-0.816-0.345t-0.345-0.816z">
            <Path.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Path">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#444"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Path.Style>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
```